# Why it shows module 'nilearn' has no attribute 'plotting'?

Tags: python, nilearn

When I run

```
nilearn.plotting.plot_connectome()
```

it shows me that module 'nilearn' has no attribute 'plotting', how is it possible? I have reinstalled the nilearn library many times and ran the code on a different computer, but it didn't work.
Does anyone know the reason and how to solve this error? Thank you for any help!

Comment: How are you importing `nilearn`

Comment: import nilearn
and I use the nilearn.plotting.plot_connectome()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import nilearn`, you should import it as `import nilearn.plotting`.

Answer (score 0):

`nilearn` does not automatically import the submodules such as `plotting`. This is usually done to save memory and/or improve performance since there could be hundreds of submodules or each submodule could be very large or the submodule is not frequently used.

There could be other reasons and the decision to automatically import submodules ultimately depend on the library's author(s) which in turn could be based on the usage patterns of the library.

As the submodule `plotting` is not automatically imported you have to import it explicitly. This can be done in two ways:

- ```
  import nilearn
  import nilearn.plotting
  ```
- ```
  import nilearn
  from nilearn import plotting
  ```

Also, `plot_connectome` requires at least two arguments - 'adjacency_matrix' and 'node_coords' which I don't see in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very curious. Yesterday it didn't work. But today it works after I retried. Now on my computer,

```
from nilearn import plotting
```

works.